# How &(*x) works? Details below

Tags: c, address-operator

```
int a = 1;
int* x = &a;
//-> &*x equal to &a
```

If the pointer `x` has the adress of `a` and `*x` points to `a`'s value, compiler couldn't know that `*x` was referring to exactly `a`, it could only know `a`'s value if I pass `*x`.

But turns out it knows. So how does this work? does compiler pass the adress too or is it just cancelling `*` when I put `&` like `&*x` compiles as if its just like `x` or the other way?

Comment: If I give you the address of a person, could you tell me the address of the person who lives there without knowing who that is?

Comment: More technically (but still informally), `*x` doesn't point to `a`'s value, `*x` *is* `a`. And since `*x` and `a` are the same thing, and a thing can only be in one location, ...

Comment: @molbdnilo I think OP's question is more like: if I tell you the name of a person, can you tell me the address? That's what `&(*p)` should be interpreted like, if the operators are evaluated in order. Silly I know, but still.

Comment: Yes could you know a persons adress if i tell you the name

Comment: "does compiler pass it adress too [...]?" The address of `a` (`&a`) is stored in `x`. So `*x` and `*&a` both refer to the same object (_lvalue_) as `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1`, `a`, `x`, `*x` are all *expressions*.

Some expressions have addresses (they are called "lvalues"), others don't (they are called "rvalues").

`1` is a rvalue, it doesn't have an address. So `&1` doesn't compile.

`a` is an lvalue, so it does have an address.

`*x` is also an lvalue, so it too has an address. This is just how the language works. It could've been made differently (`*x` could've been an rvalue), but it was made an lvalue, because it's convenient to have the address available.

For the operator `&`, there's no difference between `a` and `*x`, since both have the same value category (both are lvalues).

You seem to have assumed (even without knowing the terms) that only variable names are lvalues (only they have addresses), which is not the case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes thats what i was looking for

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't notice the C tag. D: Thanks, edited.

Comment: @namenamename You're welcome. But I mistook this for a C++ question, and explained the C++ theory instead of C. I edited the answer slightly to use the correct terms.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Its ok but what about temporary variables in c++, are they rvalues or temporary lvalues? like int{4} or classname()

Comment: or are they just constants

Comment: @namenamename Objects are not the same thing as expressions. Objects are essentially regions of memory, existing while your program is running. But expressions are merely writings in the source code, existing at compile-time. Being a temporary is a property of an object, while the value category (lvalue vs rvalue) is a property of an expression. Consider `const int &ref = 42;`. Expression `42` is an rvalue, and it referes to a temporary object. But expression `ref` is an lvalue, even though it refers to the same temporary object.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the `&(*x)`, from `C11`, chapter 6.5.3.2,

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type *type*, the result has type *pointer to type*. If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue. [...]

Comment: So the compiler automatically cancels both? If it didn't and converted to exe directly it wouldn't make sense am i right?

Comment: This is true from C99 really

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I just had C11 doc handy for quoting :)

Comment: @namenamename Even though they cancel each other out when written right next to each other, it would work even without it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can you explain me how? isn't *x just merely a's value?

Comment: Oh, it's §6.5.3.2 if you want to quote C99 too ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)).

Comment: @namenamename: I wouldn't say it's `a`'s value. Rather it **is** `a`.

Comment: @namenamename regardless of what `*a` means (value or not), the language specification precisely says that if you have a `&` applied directly on a `*` then the two operators cancel each other and the result of the expression shall be the exact same as without them, so that's what is happening.

Comment: @namenamename `*x` and `a` are the same _lvalue_ (locator value), i.e. they are the same object, so have the same address.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of the form `&*p` has some special considerations. It is **not** evaluated by first evaluating `*p` and taking the address of that, but rather the `&` and `*` cancel, to yield simply `p`.

This allows you to write something like

```
#include <iostream> 
int main() {
    int* p = nullptr; 
    int* q = &*p;
    std::cout << p << q;
}
```

without any undefined behaviour.

Comment: While true, OP's code would work even without those special considerations.

Comment: Is blackcat right about what he is saying? Can you explain

Comment: @namenamename: It's true I was concentrating more on "when i put & like &*x compiles as if its just like x or the other way" in my answer. HolyBlackCat is talking about the two lines of code.